# How to install pygresql in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pygresql

when I try to install it via pip, or  easy_install,  it gives me error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/include/pgsql/server'
```

How should I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the PostgreSQL server include files or they are not located at the expected path on your system. See [PyGreSQL Installation](http://www.pygresql.org/install.html) for more details on PyGreSQL compilation.

For example, on Ubuntu, you need to install [postgresql-server-dev-all](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/postgresql-server-dev-all) package to have server include files. On Fedora, it's [postgresql-devel](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=postgresql-devel).

Usually, pip will then use pg_config to find the correct path for these files.

```
$ pg_config --includedir-server
/usr/include/postgresql/9.1/server
```

Based on your error, pg_config has returned `'/usr/include/pgsql/server'` as the location of server header files but they have not been installed on your system.

Comment: pygresql is installed and working correctly on the system, I just cant get it to work on virtualenv. I should probably make some symlinks, but dont know where.

Comment: What is your distribution? Have you tried to launch 'pg_config --includedir-server'?

Comment: It gives me the same path, '/usr/include/pgsql/server'

Comment: You surely need to install a development package. Have you compiled postgresql or have you installed a package? What is your Linux distribution name and version?

Comment: It's fedora 16. How can I need any more packages, when pygresql is working outside of virtualenv?

Comment: Working or compiling? /usr/include/pgsql/server is packaged in postgresql-devel packages on Fedora: 'sudo yum install postgresql-devel'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11526/discussion-between-euphorbium-and-math)

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the build dependencies for the package.

In Debian-baseds operating systems, this would be:

`sudo apt-get build-dep psycopg2`

You should also install the `build-essentials` package (if not already installed). Then you can continue with the virtualenv installation.